# Monitorar os insert/delete/update realizados SQL SERVER 2014

Tags: sql-server

Alguém sabe como registrar os *insert/delete/update* realizada no banco de dados fora da aplicação ou restringindo por usuário?

Por exemplo somente via *SQLMAnager* somente,

O Banco é SQL Server 2014;

Comment: Verifiquei que posso realizar o monitoramento por trigger ou por change data capture do SQL server, existem outras opções, ou alguma observação referente a eles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O *[change data capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc645937(v=sql.120).aspx)* (CDC) é uma opção; teve a oportunidade de ler o artigo [SQL Server Security Audit Basics](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-security-audit-basics/)?

O assunto é extenso para tratar em tópico de fórum, mas há vários artigos na web que tratam sobre [auditoria](https://www.google.com.br/search?client=ubuntu&q=sql%20server%20audit).

Há scripts prontos específicos para [auditoria](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/site/search?query=audit&f%5B1%5D.Value=audit&f%5B1%5D.Type=SearchText&f%5B0%5D.Value=SQL&f%5B0%5D.Type=ProgrammingLanguage&f%5B0%5D.Text=SQL&ac=2), que você pode adaptar ao que necessita.

Answer (score 0):

Sem usar auditoria, somente via Trigger. Usando esse modelo de criação de Trigger via SQL Dinamico, voce pode monitorar as ações.

Crie antes sua tabela de _LOG e adicione abaixo.

```
DECLARE @tablename VARCHAR(100) 
DECLARE @audittable VARCHAR(100) 
DECLARE @sqlInsert VARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @sqlColumns VARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @sqlJoin VARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @sqlWhere VARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @sqlWhereFinal VARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @sqlHeader VARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @quote CHAR(1) 
SET @quote = CHAR(39) 

SET @tablename = 'SUA_TABELA'        --Replace this with the table name for which you want to write the update trigger 
SET @audittable = 'SUA_TABELA_LOG'        --Replace this with the audit table you want to insert the changed data 

--this is just the header info  for the trigger 
SET @sqlHeader = 'IF OBJECT_ID('+@quote+''+@tablename+'_U'+@quote+') IS NOT NULL 
       DROP TRIGGER dbo.'+@tablename+'_U 
GO 

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.'+@tablename+'_U 
ON dbo.'+@tablename+' FOR update 
/************************************************************** 
* Update trigger for '+@tablename+' 
* 
* MODIFICATIONS 
* 01/01/2000 xxx New 
**************************************************************/ 
AS ' 
PRINT @sqlHeader 

--select insert into 
SELECT @sqlInsert = COALESCE(@sqlInsert+' ,' , '') + name + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(9)  FROM sys.syscolumns WHERE OBJECT_NAME(id) = @tablename ORDER BY colid 
SET @sqlInsert = 'insert into dbo.'+@audittable+'('+CHAR(13) +CHAR(9)+@sqlInsert +')' 
PRINT @sqlInsert 

-- select col list 
SELECT @sqlColumns = COALESCE(@sqlColumns+' ,' , '') +'d.'+ name + CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) FROM sys.syscolumns WHERE OBJECT_NAME(id) = @tablename ORDER BY colid 
SET @sqlColumns = 'select '+CHAR(13) +CHAR(9)+ @sqlColumns  

--strip the last linebreak 
SET @sqlColumns = LEFT(@sqlColumns, (LEN(@sqlColumns)-2)) 
PRINT @sqlColumns 

--generate the join condition between Inserted and Deleted tables if the table has Primary key 
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE   WHERE table_name  = @tablename AND constraint_name LIKE '%PK%') 
BEGIN 
               SET @sqlJoin = '' 
               SELECT @sqlJoin = COALESCE(@sqlJoin , '') + 'd.'+ column_name + ' = i.'+ column_name + CHAR(13)+CHAR(9) +' and ' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE table_name = @tablename AND constraint_name LIKE '%PK%' 
               SET @sqlJoin = 'from ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + ' deleted d join inserted i on ' + @sqlJoin  
               --strip off the last 'and' 
               SET @sqlJoin = LEFT(@sqlJoin, (LEN(@sqlJoin)-6)) 
END 
ELSE 
       SET @sqlJoin = 'from deleted d, inserted i' 

PRINT @sqlJoin 

--generate the != clause where you check if atleast one column is changed... 
DECLARE @coltype VARCHAR(100) 
DECLARE @colname VARCHAR(100) 
SET @sqlWhereFinal = 'where'   

DECLARE colcursor CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY  READ_ONLY FOR SELECT st.name, sc.name 
FROM sys.syscolumns sc JOIN sys.systypes st ON sc.xtype = st.xtype  
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(sc.id) = @tablename AND sc.name NOT IN 
(SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE   WHERE table_name  = @tablename AND constraint_name LIKE '%PK%') 

OPEN colcursor 
FETCH next FROM colcursor INTO @coltype , @colname 
WHILE @@fetch_status = 0 
BEGIN 
       SET @sqlWhere = '' 
       PRINT @sqlWhereFinal 
       SET @sqlWhereFinal         = '' 
       SET @sqlWhere = CASE WHEN @coltype IN('smalldatetime','datetime','sql_variant','ntext','varbinary','varchar','binary','char','timestamp','nvarchar','nchar','xml','sysname') 
                                               THEN  @sqlWhere + CHAR(9) + 'isnull(d.'+ @colname +','''') != isnull(i.'+ @colname + ','''') or'   
                                               ELSE 
                                                          @sqlWhere + CHAR(9) + 'isnull(d.'+ @colname +',-1) != isnull(i.'+ @colname + ',-1) or' 
                                               END 
       SET @sqlWhereFinal = @sqlWhereFinal + @sqlWhere  
       FETCH next FROM colcursor INTO @coltype , @colname 
END 
CLOSE colcursor 
DEALLOCATE colcursor 

--remove the last 'or' 
SET @sqlWhereFinal = LEFT(@sqlWhereFinal, (LEN(@sqlWhereFinal)-3)) 
PRINT @sqlWhereFinal
```